# How to set cookies for webview in android through coding

Tags: android, cookies

How to set cookies for webview in android through coding?

where the cookies get stored in android device memory??

and how to open the stored cookies in android devices,is it really possible to see the cookies in android device??

Answer (score 0):

Use the CookieManager to set and get the cookies for websites in the WebView
Refer to the following link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

Answer (score 0):

To Set the cookies in Android **CookieManager** is used. To set the cookies you only have to create an instance of this Class. But cookie is a set of key and value. There is a particular format to create a string to be fed in set cookie method. If we have three pairs we will write **cookieString = "fruit=apple; animal=dog; flower=rose"** and the other important thing is url. You have have to define the url for which you want to set cookies **url = "https://www.google.com/"**

```
private var cookieManager: CookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance() 
val url = "https://www.google.com/"
cookieString = "fruit=apple; animal=dog; flower=rose"

webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webViewReach, true);
cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookieString)
webView.loadUrl(url)
```

After setting the cookie you don't have to bother about set the cookie manager anywhere, its just set, Now the only thing you have to do is load the url in your web view